# Generating all binary combinations of 2d array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to generate all possible 2D arrays (of size `n*n`) of `0` and `1`. Since there are two choices for each entry of the 2D array, there are `2^{n^2}` such arrays that need to be generated.

I have a code that generates all possible 1D arrays (of size `n`) of `0` and `1`. It is:

```
def generateAllSpinConfigs(n,arr,l,i):
    if i == n: 
        l.append(arr[:]) 
        return

    arr[i] = 0
    generateAllSpinConfigs(n,arr,l,i+1)  
    arr[i] = 1
    generateAllSpinConfigs(n,arr,l,i+1)  

    return l

arr=[None]*n 
l=[]
answer=generateAllSpinConfigs(n,arr,l,0)
```

I understand how that works. In this recursive code, the lowest function call returns an array of all `0` first, then an array with all `0` with a `1` in the last location and so on.
Can we extend this logic to generate all `2D` arrays or is there a Python function that does the job that I'm not aware of?

Comment: [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) has the ability to generate combinations.

Comment: Consider that a binary array can be seen a number. A 2D array of dimension `(x, y)` has `x * y = n` bits. The number of combination is `2^n` or `2^(x*y)`. So, for example, an 4x4 array would be `2^16 = 65535` combinations. A 6x6 is would have 68719476736 combination, larger than what can fit in an int. It quickly gets out of hand.

Comment: Due to the above, a recursive algorithm won't get far.

Comment: @Ouroborus True, it increases exponentially. Thanks, I am aware of `itertools.combinations` but it doesn't have an option for a 2D array?

Comment: @Ouroborus I will be running the algorithm for small `n`.

Comment: @Ouroborus *"larger than what can fit in an int"*? We're talking about Python.

Comment: Yes. So the arrays will be far larger.

Comment: A `x*y` 2d array is the same as a `n`-length 1d array, where `x*y = n`. Generate the 1d array, then reshape it to 2d.

Comment: @Ouroborus Huh? Far larger than what?

Comment: For generation, speed, storage efficiency, and the capability your asking about, you might look at [numpy](https://numpy.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`. First to generate 1-dimensional lists, and then again to use that as a basis to increase the dimension:

```
from itertools import product

def get_bin_rows(size):
    return product(range(2), repeat=size)

def get_bin_matrices(size):
    return product(get_bin_rows(size), repeat=size)
```

Example use for `n=2`:

```
for matrix in get_bin_matrices(2):
    # print matrix row by row
    for row in matrix:
        print(*row)
    print()  # separate matrix outputs
```